# Determine Even Number From File

Tags: java, file-io

Good day sir. My teacher told us to take all the even numbers from the input file. But the even number keeps telling me that it's 23 evens and it should be 8 and 66.67%. My input from file is:

5 7 2 8 9 10 12 98 7 14 20 22 (with white spaces)

and my code is:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class number2 {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("number.txt"));
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int evenCount = 0;
        float percent = 0;
        while(input.hasNextInt()) {
            int num = input.nextInt();
            sum+=num;
            count++;
            evenCount = evenNumber(num, count);
        }
        percent = (evenCount*100)/count;
        System.out.println("\n" +count + " Numbers, " + "Sum = " +sum);
        System.out.println( evenCount + " evens " +"(" + percent +"%)");   
    }

    public static int evenNumber(int counter, int number){
        if(number%2==0)
            counter++;
        return counter;

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're calling the `evenNumber`method with the switched parameters...

```
while(input.hasNextInt()){
    int num = input.nextInt();
    sum+=num;
    count++;
    //first parameter is number read from file, second parameter is the current count
    evenCount = evenNumber(num, count);}
    //...
```

On your method `evenNumber`method signature you have

```
//first parameter is the counter, second parameter is the read number
public static int evenNumber(int counter, int number)
```

You should switch the parameters being called inside the `evenNumber`method in the while block:
    `evenCount = evenNumber(evenCount, num)`

Also, you should pass `evenCount`to the `evenNumber`method instead of count, otherwise you will be increasing the count of all numbers instead the count for only even numbers.